# MySQL shell connection failed

Tags: mysql, shell

I attempted to connect to `000webhost`'s database server by `MySQL shell(version 1.0.10)` but connection failed error.

This is the error message:

```
mysql-js> \connect xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@databases.000webhost.com
Creating a Session to 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@databases.000webhost.com'
Enter password: *********
ERROR: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'databases.000webhost.com' (10061)
```

`xxxx`... is my database account name and `databases.000webhost.com` is the host name.

The default setting is

```
DB Name: 
yyyyyyyyyy 

DB User:
xxxxxxxxxxxxxx

DB Host:
localhost
```

It's remote database so I tried to use host `'databases.000webhost.com'` rather than `'localhost'`

but it failed error.

The login page of phpmyadmin was displayed when I typed `'databases.000webhost.com'` in address bar.

Comment: There may be a firewall blocking the connection.

Comment: Is it shared hosted MySQL db ??